# Routing Traffic via Common Ip Address from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, proxy, ip, http-proxy

I have developed a Chrome extension and over 50 people are using it. The Chrome Extension logins into the paid account of a website which I have purchased and then scrapes some content from that website and returns results to users. Right now requests is going from User's Ip Address hence the website which I scrape bans my paid account.

I want all requests to go from a particular ip address so that irrespective of the number of users using the chrome extension, the requesting ip address always remains the same - kind of http-proxy.

What is the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: Extensions can't change the IP address of requests. You need a real proxy or a real VPN for that.

Comment: i am not saying extensions to change ip address. but can i programmatically configure browsers of users to use proxy server whenever my extension is used?

Comment: Extensions can configure the user's proxy using chrome.proxy API, see the documentation.

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know. this is the first step. i will check that. now lets talk about server side. is it a good idea to install a proxy server on the windows server or create my own http proxy service on the server side in C# etc?

Comment: To my limited knowledge any approach is fine as long as it works for you. In the future if your user base grows you may want to find a solution that stresses the CPU as little as possible so that it can serve more users concurrently.

Comment: makes sense. I will update this question once i have implemented the POC so that it is helpful for the community as well.